# S3 bucket versioning suspended but toggling show versions on still shows deleted files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an S3 bucket with versioning enabled and later realized that I don't need to keep multiple versions. I suspended versioning but when I delete a file, and click on show versions, it is showing `Delete marker` under "Type" and Version ID: null and Size 0 Bytes.

So I don't understand what's the point of suspending the versioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Deleting objects from versioning-suspended buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DeletingObjectsfromVersioningSuspendedBuckets.html):

> You can delete objects from versioning-suspended buckets to remove an object with a null version ID.
>
> If versioning is suspended for a bucket, a DELETE request:
>
> - Can only remove an object whose version ID is null.
> - Doesn't remove anything if there isn't a null version of the object in the bucket.
> - **Inserts a delete marker into the bucket.**

I suspect this is because deleting an object does not automatically delete all of the prior versions. Instead, it only deletes the "current" object. However, if the "current object" is a version (that is, there are previous versions of the object), it will still use a Delete Marker to simply hide the current version.

If you wish to delete the whole object (including previous versions), you will need to turn on "Show versions" and delete all of the previous versions.

Comment: I created a file after suspending versioning and then deleted it. So does that mean that I can ignore that file with delete Delete Marker (when show versions is turned on). It's 0 bytes  and for practical purpose cannot be recovered right? If I understand correctly, NULL version ID means that there are no other versions of the object to be recovered ?

Comment: When an object is initially created, it has a Version of NULL. (At least it does that for a non-Versioning bucket. Not sure about a Versioned bucket.)

Comment: You are right. There is only a delete marker next to filename after deleting the file on a suspended versioning bucket. There is no option to restore so it's not taking up any space or storing other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Response from John is correct.  Another option would be to enable a lifecycle rule on the bucket that deletes versions.

Comment: Well, I issue is that after suspending versioning, there shouldn’t be any versions to begin with. If I delete a file, it’s still showing the file but with NULL version. I am thinking it’s just a marker and not something that takes space. It’s 0 bytes.